# Custom Module not Displaying in App List in Odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

So I've been stuck on this all day and I'm desperate at this point.

I've been learning about Odoo since yesterday. I created a custom Python module. Here's the code in the **field.py**

```
class Field(models.Model):
   _name = "challenge.field"

   name = fields.Char("Full Name", required=True)
   email_address = fields.Char("Email Address")
```

Here's what is in the **views.xml**

```
<odoo>
   <menuitem name="Challenge" id="challenge_root_menu"/>

   <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_challenge_field">
     <field name="name">Field</field>
     <field name="res_model">challenge.field</field>
     <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
   </record>
</odoo>
```

Here's the **security.xml**

```
<odoo>
    <record id="testers" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Testers Challenge</field>
    </record>

</odoo>
```

And finally here's the **ir.model.access.csv**

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
my_challenge,challenge.field,model_challenge_field,testers,1,1,1,1
```

No matter what I do, the app does not appear in the app field, and thus I can't launch it.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cazP.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `action` to menuitem record.

```
<menuitem name="Challenge" id="challenge_root_menu" action="action_challenge_field" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be 2 Reasons that you are not able to see the module :-

**1.** **You have not updated the database**

**Two ways to update the database :-**

**1.1 from Terminal use this command to update the module and database**

> ./odoo-bin -c debian/odoo.conf -d {NAME_OF_ODOO_DATABASE} -u
>   {NAME_OF_THE_NEW_MODULE}

**1.2. From frontend**

By activating the developer mode by going to *Setting* --> under the *developer tools option* --> *Activate the developer mode*

Now go to app list and select the option *update app list*.

**2.** **You have not configured the addons path in the debian/odoo.conf file**

Make sure that you have added the addons_path of the custom-addons folder in odoo.conf file inside debian folder

**Note::** Dont forget to remove semicolon before the addons_path

[image: odoo.conf file structure]